# MKMapView not updating overlay correctly, delay on showing MKPolyline

Tags: cocoa, mkmapview

The problem is that when I add a Polyline to the MapView ... The Polyline was shown with a random delay. Somtimes it tooks 1sec sometimes 5sec

This is the function which draws the Polyline.

```
- (void) setRoutePoints:(NSArray*)locations {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *pointsCoOrds = (CLLocationCoordinate2D*)malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [locations count]);
    NSUInteger i, count = [locations count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CLLocation* obj = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        pointsCoOrds[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(obj.coordinate.latitude, obj.coordinate.longitude);
    }

    [mapView addOverlay:[MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsCoOrds count:locations.count]];
    free(pointsCoOrds);
}
```

The Callback function needed (see Apple Docs) is also correct

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineView* routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.5f];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 8;
        return routeLineView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

And this is how I call the function to add the Polyline

```
[self setRoutePoints:steps];
```

The only problem is that the delay at which the polyline is drawn on the map is random.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved my problem is to call the

```
setTheRoutePoints
```

function on the main thread.

This eliminated the delay in which the polyline was shown.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setRoutePoints:) withObject:steps waitUntilDone:NO];
```